# Can Nginx automatically update the upstream servers details without Nginx reload

Tags: nginx, nginx-upstreams

I am seeing nginx upstream as follows

```
upstream entities {
    server entities.qa.local:8888;
}
upstream workflow {
    server workflow.qa.local:9999;
}
```

Some times server went down and up on its own at that time their internal ips will get change.
After that nginx will not update with new IP until we reload the Nginx.

Can we update those ips without Nginx reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a trick on this article, you can try to add the resolver and store your URL in a variable. Nginx will use DNS in this resolver when calculating the variable. This article: https://docs.wallarm.com/admin-en/configure-dynamic-dns-resolution-nginx/

Comment: But this doesn't support multiple upstreams - how do you handle multiple upstreams?